# How to start/open SQL Server Express 2008 in Visual Studio?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have Windows 8 and have installed full-pack Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition. There was no error while installing Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition.

I exactly don't know which edition and version of SQL Server it installed.

Therefore, please help me to determine, which edition and version of SQL Server it has installed and also how to start SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can open Server Explorer in View menu of vs 2010

[image]

create a new one

[image]

You can else open command prompt

type `ssms` sql server management studio will executed

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and quickest way to see if and what edition was installed is to run SERVICES.MSC and check for the installed service. To get to SERVICES.MSC, open

> **Control Panel ➮ Administrative Tools ➮ Services**

then scroll down the list looking for SQL Server.

I have installed both Full and Express editions of SQL, side-by-side. The screenshot below shows what to look for. The Express edition is denoted by an instance name of SQLEXPRESS.

[image: Screenshot]

Notice at the right, I have SQL Express Disabled and MSSQLSERVER is Running. You can start SQL Express here if it's not running. You can also set it to start automatically on boot.

To launch SQL Server Management Studio, you'll want to look for it on your Start screen. It may look something like:

[image: Control Panel]

If it's not there, you can get the 2005 version directly from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961), or the 2008 version from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593). You'll probably want the 2008 version.

Finally, you could also go for SQL Server 2012 Express [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062), which includes Management Studio Express, however, you'd probably have to uninstall whatever Express edition you have installed now.

I hope I haven't muddied that water for you. I'd be happy to clarify or answer any additional questions you have.